# statechange load is causing multiple loads of the same page

Tags: jquery, ajax, browser-history, history.js, html5-history

It appears that this line in the `statechange` event:

`$('#content').load(State.data.home_page);`

...is causing the same page to load multiple times which is resulting in glitches on my site. What can I do to fix this?

[image]

```
(function($) {

    function loadHome() {
        $('#content').load(site.url + '/ #primary', function() {
            $(this).fadeIn(50);
        });
    }

    // User event
    $('.site-title a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var newData = { home_page: site.url + '/ #primary' };
        History.pushState(newData, site.title, site.url);
        loadHome();
    });

    // History event
    History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function(){
        var State = History.getState();
        $('#content').load(State.data.home_page);
    });

})(jQuery);
```

### Update

Ok, so I learned that `.pushState` actually calls `statechange`.

So basically, I'm thinking this is what's happening:

- User clicks on `.site-title a`
- `pushState()` is called which calls `statechange` which loads the part of the page.
- At the same time, `loadHome()` is also called which loads the same.

I can see that is why I am getting multiple instances of the same page. I thought `statechange` is only called when the user clicks the back button on the browser. That kind of clears things up, but I'm still at a loss as to how to move forward with this. I'm not sure what to replace that `.load` line with in the `statechange` event, assuming that's the culprit.

Comment: you are  binding an event handler inside another event handler. Every time you click a link, will add it  again

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks, I fixed that. However, I have another problem now. I updated my post with it.

Answer (score 1):

When you click the link the following happens, in order:

1. You push new state onto the stack
2. The state change event fires
3. The event initiates a load of `data.home_page`
4. `loadHome` is called
5. `loadHome` initiates a load

As you can see, steps 3 and 5 are redundant.

Can you instead bind to the `popstate` event?

- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#handler-window-onpopstate
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onpopstate